# What's faster in terms of performance? <video> or <canvas>

Tags: html, canvas, three.js, html5-video

I want to display an animated 3D model on a page, I have 2 solutions:

1). Use [threejs](https://threejs.org/) (or similar library), import the FBX model and animate it in `<canvas>`

2). Use my favourite 3D modelling software, capture a looping animation and display it as a video using `<video>`

Solution 2 will be the fastest in terms of time to implement, but obviously the has more limitations over solution 1. In terms of performance however, which solution would be the better choice?

The length of the full animation will be around 20-30 seconds, the size of the exported model is around 60KB and the minified threejs library itself is around 470KB.

Worth nothing: the model itself is a low poly mesh with a simple looping motion and a few bones.

Comment: Video will be resolution dependent. But if you okay with that - you could potentially render video with much more quality than with real time. From the other side - you could add a lot of interactivity with real time rendering. Also notice that WebGL support coverage is not 100%.

Comment: Good point, some browsers we wish to support don't (Android 4.4.4 for example). The video quality will need to be quite high (feature will be used as cover image). Thanks for the comment.

Comment: As the model has such a low memory footprint and implementing both methods is very simple, do both. If no 3D support use video, else use 3D. Unless you have very complex shaders you should have no problem with performance for such a small model, while a video may be enough to lose a client (3 second rule) especially if they have a top end device (video is not 3D!!)

Comment: Hmm hadn't thought of it that way, a video may provide excellent fallback. I would personally prefer to take the 3D route, but now to convince that client! Thanks for your help.